# Do some Bone Constraints only work with Root Bones?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

While the *Floor* and *Limit Distance* constraints work well with the root bones of an armature. I don't get them to work with other non root bones. Is there any reason for that or do I miss a detail?

[image]

In this setup the armature shown on the right has a *Limit Distance* constraint when moving the slider Distance the whole armature moves. What I would like to achieve is that the tip is moving but a constraint at the right tip targeting the left tip seems to have  no effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Limit Distance* constraint influences the location of the bone. All the bones (except the root bone) are children of another bone in the armature. Because of this you cannot move them (the location is also greyed out in the properties panel). If you want to allow the tip to move, you should un-parent the tip, create an IK constraint on the bone beneath it, and target the tip bone. That should make it work.

[image: constraint explanation]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to set a *Children Of* constraint to the left bone targeting the controlling right bone.

[image]